# i want to know is there any other file needed along WINDOWS UBUNTU INSTALLER install ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

i want to know is there any other file needed along WINDOWS UBUNTU INSTALLER install ubuntu?
i only try windows installer with no other file......but fail
please answer me properly and easily like a begineer

Answer (score 0):

1. Please download the ubuntu iso file from the ubuntu website (not the torrent file).
2. Open the downloaded .iso file with winzip or wirar
3. Go to bottom of the file to find "wubi.exe" extract it to the same folder that has the iso file.
4. Execute the wubi.exe file.

For more info please check the below link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

Please don't forget to click on the UP arrow beside this answer to mark it as useful

Thanks